# Brew fails to install coreutils when it tries to download a version of attr that doesn't exist

Tags: homebrew, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running an Ubuntu terminal inside WSL and I'm having troubles installing `coreutils` using the following command:

```
brew install coreutils
```

When I try this I get the following response:

```
==> Downloading https://linuxbrew.bintray.com/bottles/attr-2.5.1.x86_64_linux.bottle.tar.gz
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

Error: Failed to download resource "attr"
Download failed: https://linuxbrew.bintray.com/bottles/attr-2.5.1.x86_64_linux.bottle.tar.gz
```

I took a look in the directory for the `.tar.gz` and found there's a file for 2.4.47 and 2.4.48, but not the 2.5.1 that brew is attempting to find

I've tried `brew install attr@2.4.47` but that doesn't get anywhere

Any help would be appreciated as to how I can solve this problem and get `coreutils` installed!

Comment: Did you update and upgrade brew before attempting this download?  I ask because I’ve had issues with this in the past...  also I had to reinstall Xcode last night because my upgrade command kept failing.

Comment: I've only just installed Brew, but gave updating & upgrading a go but still no dice. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Just so I’m not quoting someone else’s findings, check out the top voted answer in this stack query.  This might help. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities/69332#69332

Comment: That solves it, thank you so much! None of my googling would have landed me anywhere near that question so you've saved me a lot of time and headaches 